# Joining two subqueries that were created from the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, cartesian-product

I have a table TABLE1 with columns:

```
key, person, date, type, trait1, trait2, trait3, trait4, trait 5
```

Now say I create two temporary tables from TABLE1:

```
create temp1 as
select key, person, date, trait1, trait2
from TABLE1
where trait1=trait2

create temp2 as
select key, person, type, trait3, trait4
from TABLE1
where type='A' and trait3=trait4
```

If I were to then join the tables like this:

```
create table TABLE2 as
select A.key, A.person, A.date, B.type, A.trait1, A.trait2, B.trait3, B.trait4
from temp1 A, temp2 B
where A.key = B.key and A.person=B.person
```

Would I get the same result as if I were to create TABLE 2 from the original TABLE1 like this:

```
create table TABLE2 as
select key, person, date, type, trait1, trait2, trait3, trait4
from TABLE 1
where trait1=trait2 and type='A' and trait3=trait4
```

Logically this seems like it would yield the same result, correct? This example is mainly to illustrate my question: If you filter a table into two subtables based on a different condition for each, and then join them like this, will the result be the same as if you simply filtered the original table for both conditions?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Does `person`/`key` uniquely define each row?

Comment: Either way it would be unnecessary. You can join a table to itself therefore removing the need to duplicate the data.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `key`/`person` uniquely define each row, then the results are going to be really, really close.  The join is going to combine a row that matches the first condition with itself, but only if it matches the second condition.

When would they be different?  That would be when the condition `A.key = B.key and A.person = B.person` fails to get the matching row.  This would happen when either `key` or `person` were `NULL`.

Of course, if `key`/`person` do *not* uniquely identify a given row, then it is trivial that the two methods are different.